# Maybe in a monad

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I want to learn to use Haskell the right way.

I still don't fully understand how to use Maybe as a monad inside another monad. http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads tells me that I can do wonderful things with Maybe without pattern matching Just and Nothing at every step. Please help me understand how.

I'm writing a Yesod handler, but that doesn't matter in this case. All that matters is that Handler is a monad.

```
ugly :: Maybe ByteString -> Maybe MyObj
ugly Nothing = Nothing
ugly (Just text) = (decode . fromStrict) text

getHelloWorldR :: Handler Html
getHelloWorldR = do
  myObjText <- lookupSessionBS "myobj"  :: Handler (Maybe ByteString) -- gets serialized MyObj from a session cookie, or Nothing
  myObj <- return $ ugly myObjText :: Handler (Maybe MyObj)
```

How can I rewrite it to avoid pattern matching on Nothing?

I tried using `>>=` but it expects strange types of function and returns strange types. I just can't make it work. I looked at `MaybeT`, but that means that I need to define a function similar to `ugly` in my example, that returns a `MaybeT Handler MyObj`. Seems too complicated.

Edit: replaced lookupSession with lookupSessionBS that returns a ByteString.

Comment: Just define `ugly :: ByteString -> MyObj`; then `fmap ugly :: Maybe ByteString -> Maybe MyObj`.

Comment: I can't, because Aeson.decode returns `Maybe MyObj`.

Comment: "`>>=` expects strange types of function and returns strange types" you need to dwell on it until those stop looking strange to you. also check out the `>=>` Kleisli composition operator. Monad Laws are easier to grasp with it. "Monad axioms: Kleisli composition forms a category".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getHelloWorldR = do
  myObjText <- lookupSession "myobj"  :: Handler (Maybe Text)
  myObj <- return $ ugly myObjText :: Handler (Maybe MyObj)
  ...
```

can be rewritten as

```
getHelloWorldR = do
  myObjText <- lookupSession "myobj"  :: Handler (Maybe Text)
  let myObj = ugly myObjText :: Maybe MyObj
  ...
```

Then,

```
ugly :: Maybe Text -> Maybe MyObj
ugly Nothing = Nothing
ugly (Just text) = (decode . encodeUtf8 . fromStrict) text
```

can be rewritten as

```
ugly :: Maybe Text -> Maybe MyObj
ugly maytext = maytext >>= decode . encodeUtf8 . fromStrict
```

Hence,

```
getHelloWorldR = do
  myObjText <- lookupSession "myobj"  :: Handler (Maybe Text)
  let myObj :: Maybe MyObj
      myObj = myObjTest >>= decode . encodeUtf8 . fromStrict
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining each step. I couldn't make a transition to using `>>=` in `ugly`, but it is indeed very easy!

Answer (score 2):

Since based on the type signature `decode . encodeUtf8 . fromString` is a function `Text -> Maybe MyObj`, we can here use `(>>=)` or its flipped counterpart [**`(=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-61--60--60-):

```
ugly :: Maybe Text -> Maybe MyObj
ugly = (=<<) (decode . encodeUtf8 . fromStrict)
```

or shorter:

```
ugly :: Maybe Text -> Maybe MyObj
ugly = (decode . encodeUtf8 . fromStrict =<<)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t even need monads here — you can rewrite `ugly` using `fmap`:

```hs
ugly = fmap $ decode . fromStrict
```

At which point you can even inline it into `getHelloWorldR`:

```hs
getHelloWorldR :: Handler Html
getHelloWorldR = do
  myObjText <- lookupSessionBS "myobj"  :: Handler (Maybe ByteString) -- gets serialized MyObj from a session cookie, or Nothing
  myObj <- return $ fmap (decode . fromStrict) myObjText :: Handler (Maybe MyObj)
```

Or you could even use the `<$>` operator, which is an infix version of `fmap`:

```hs
getHelloWorldR :: Handler Html
getHelloWorldR = do
  myObjText <- lookupSessionBS "myobj"  :: Handler (Maybe ByteString) -- gets serialized MyObj from a session cookie, or Nothing
  myObj <- return $ (decode . fromStrict) <$> myObjText :: Handler (Maybe MyObj)
```

And in fact, since you’re running `return` and then immediately assigning it via `<-`, it can be replaced with a `let`:

```hs
getHelloWorldR :: Handler Html
getHelloWorldR = do
  myObjText <- lookupSessionBS "myobj"  :: Handler (Maybe ByteString) -- gets serialized MyObj from a session cookie, or Nothing
  let myObj :: Maybe MyObj
      myObj = (decode . fromStrict) <$> myObjText
```

---

But I would also like to present a slightly different view on monads to that in your question. Monads aren’t just a tool to remove pattern matching — they’re a very general abstraction over the concept of running things in sequence. For instance:

- When using `Maybe`, ‘running’ a computation consists of checking to see whether it’s `Nothing`, aborting the computation if this happens, otherwise continuing on. (This corresponds to a computation which can fail.)
- When using a list, ‘running’ a computation consists of splitting the computation into multiple parts, one for each element in the list, then joining those parts back again. (This corresponds to a nondeterministic computation.)
- When using `IO`, ‘running’ a computation is executing it on a computer.
- When using `Handler`, ‘running’ a computation is interacting with the request sent and/or responding with something.

So you shouldn’t reach for monads every time you want to manipulate a `Maybe` — on the contrary, it’s often much easier to do this without monads, as I showed above! Monads only become useful when you need to sequence things. In your example, this is the case with `Handler` — because you need to sequence multiple interactions with the request — but is not useful with `Maybe`, because you just need to apply a series of operations to a value which happens to be wrapped inside a `Maybe`.

Comment: But `ugly` returns a `Maybe MyObj`, what does `fmap` do to it? Will its type become `Maybe Text -> Maybe (Maybe MyObj)` ? I'm also surprised to see `return` outside of the do notation. I don't understand that. What does `return` "wrap" in that case?

Comment: @BloodySue Remember partial application and currying! `fmap f x` applies `f` to the value ‘inside’ `x`, so `fmap f` returns a function which, given a value `x`, returns `fmap f x`. As for `return`, usually it ‘wraps’ something to get it inside a monadic context, but as you noticed that doesn’t make sense the way I wrote it — I made a mistake, and I’ll remove it now so everything type-checks!

Comment: @BloodySue I should also mention that in cases when you’re applying something and then `return`ing it — like here — using `fmap` is almost more concise and understandable than using `>>=`, as `a >>= (\x -> return (f x))` is equal to `fmap f x`.

Comment: @BloodySue you're right about the type  `Maybe (Maybe MyObj)`. This can be turned into `Maybe MyObj` by using `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`. so we'd get `join . fmap (decode . fromStrict)` -- and that is by definition the same as `(>>= (decode . fromStrict))` === `(\ m -> m >>= (decode . fromStrict))` === `fmap fromStrict m >>= decode` === `do { x <- m ; decode (fromStrict x) }`. (`return :: Monad m => a -> m a` is a function in itself, like `join` -- it's not a part of the special `do` syntax. for `Maybe`, `return x = Just x`).

Comment: by Monad Laws, `do { x <- xs ; y <-  foo x ; return y }` === `do { x <- xs ; foo x }`. this means `do { x <- xs ; y <-  return (foo x) ; return y }` === `do { x <- xs ; return (foo x) }` (this happens to be === `fmap foo xs` === `foo <$> xs`). --- Indeed `do { x <- xs ; y <-  return (foo x) }` is invalid, incomplete. The last line in a `do` block can't be a "binding" syntax, must be of type `Monad m => m a`.